# How to check if it is the first message by a person who entered a discord server, and make a bot reply to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hey I am working on a welcome bot, and I want to check if the message sent by someone is their first so that the bot can reply with a nice welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`on_member_join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join) Function, the [`client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) Function and the [`message.reply()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reply).

Example:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == member

    message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    
    await message.reply('Hey mate! Welcome to this server!')
```

The `on_member_join()` function will get called every time a member joins the server. This will call `client.wait_for()` which looks with the `check(m)` function if the author of the message is the member who joined so if it's his first message. Then it replies with the `message.reply()` function to this message.

Comment: [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) aswell as [`Message.reply`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reply) are coroutines, they should be awaited.